# Can I use the Ubuntu 12.10 live CD to resize partions and upgrade from 12.04?

Tags: upgrade, partitioning

I am running a dual boot Ubuntu 12.04 installation with Windows 7. I have a 160GB hard drive. Currently the partitions are arranged (shown from left to right on the disk utility) sda1 (WinRE)13GB:sda2(Windows'C')52GB:sda4 with sda5 and sda6(Ubuntu 12.04)46GB:sda3 (Windows'D')49GB. I have downloaded and burnt an Ubuntu 12.10 DVD.

I want to take space from sda3 and increase the Ubuntu partition. sda3 is virtually empty (only 350MB used) because I am only using Windows for iTunes and a very few drivers/programmes that I need occasionally.

My question - can I use the Ubuntu 12.10 DVD to both change the partition scheme to increase the Ubuntu space AND upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10? If so, can anyone point me to a clear set of instructions? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Thank you fabricator4. Your answer was exactly what I was looking for. Yes, the partitions were as you thought. I have now deleted Windows D and I will extend sda4 as you suggest, leaving 5GB of unallocated space just in case I ever need it for Windows (or Ubuntu). With regard to your comments about resizing - do I need to resize the swap partition (sda6, as you suggested)? It is 2GB in size.
- I assume you mean for me to resize sda5 to 25GB? Then create a logical partion ext4 to use the rest of the space in the new extended partition sda4?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the LiveDVD to resize partitions and to upgrade.  Boot off it then select "try Ubuntu", then when it has finished booting run Gparted to alter and resize partitions.

I would actually suggest making the Ubuntu / partition smaller, say about 25GB and increasing the size of /dev/sda3 to fill the rest of the drive and format it as ext4.  You can then use this partition to mount as /home and keep all your data on it.  That way you would have about 85Gb for /home data.

I note that /dev/sda4 is probably an extended partition with (most likely) sda5 and sda6 inside it.  You'll have to resize and move those before you can resize the extended partition.  I'm thinking sda6 is most likely a swap partition.

An alternative approach would be to delete /dev/sda3 (after backing up the 350MB of data) and increasing the size of the extended partition to the end of the disk.  You could then just make another logical ext4  partition inside the extended partion, or resize/move the existing ones according to your needs.

If you want to try upgrading 12.04 boot off the LiveDVD and select the upgrade option if it offers one.  I believe this is a better and faster way of upgrading compared to doing an on-line upgrade.